# Google maps error inflating, Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I get the following error when I try to leave fragment which contains map (on back button press).

ERROR: mapInflater->Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Bellow is onCreate() method of fragment where the map is placed. And also there is a xml code of layout.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        apiRequestManager = ApiRequestManager.getInstance();
        fragmentHandler = FragmentHandlerActivityMain.getInstance(getActivity());
        session = new SessionManager(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext());

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.maps_fragment_toolbar_name));

        Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SupportMapFragment maps = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
                    if (maps != null)
                        maps.getMapAsync(MapsFragment.this);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LogUtil.getInstance().add(LogUtil.ERROR,
                            TAG, "onCreateMaps", ex);
                }
            }
        };
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }
```

Log is pointing on this layout on fragment (line 7).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".salesman.fragments.MapsFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post complete crash logs

Comment: @Vivek Mishra there is no crash, only that one line ->     manager.fragments.ManagerMapFragment: mapInflater->Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to getChildFragmentManager() instade of getSupportFragmentManager().

Need to change In Java File :

1). You need to implements OnMapReadyCallback in Your Fragment.

2). Get SupportMapFragment from View.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

3). Overrid onMapReady(GoogleMap googlMap) Method.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

**In XML File :-**

`<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".salesman.fragments.MapsFragment">`

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Please check the updated answer as per below comment:**

Now try to set MapView insted of fragment because if you use fragment inside fragment it creates lot of issues.

Need to change in JAVA Code : // Initialize GoogleMap myMap; MapView mMapView;

// OnCreateView Method MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity()); mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map); mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

@Override public void onPause() { super.onPause(); mMapView.onPause(); }

@Override public void onPause() { super.onPause(); mMapView.onPause(); }

@Overridepublic void onResume() { super.onResume(); mMapView.onResume(); }

Need to change in XML File :

`<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: Hi, I already have onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) overridden, also tried using getSupportFragmnetManager() but I get error "cannot resolve method"

Comment: Hi, I have replied on the comment by posting the updated answer under  **"Please check the updated answer as per below comment"**. Please check the answer and let me know is it worked for you.